# PHP Fatal error:Call to a member function getValue() on null in Helper/Vendor.php:107

Tags: magento2, extensions

I cloned from **github** and installed in my **magento v2.2** `app/code`. Everything seems ok, but just I see a stuck with a blank , and found an error log as above title.
 The relative two files post below. I searched here no clue found. Please give light to solve it. Thanks

**app/code/Amitshree/Marketplace/view/frontend/templates/vendor/sidebar.phtml**

```
<?php
/* @var $block \Amitshree\Marketplace\Block\Vendor\AccountDetailsSidebar */
?>
<?php
$marketplaceVendorHelper = $this->helper('Amitshree\Marketplace\Helper\Vendor');
?>
<?php if ($marketplaceVendorHelper->isVendorInfoAllowedInSidebar()) : ?>
    <div class="vendor_sidebar_additional">
        <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTitle(); ?></strong>
        <div class="vendor_account_links">
            <p><a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $marketplaceVendorHelper->getVendorProfileUrl() ?>">Profile Info</a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**app/code/Amitshree/Marketplace/Helper/Vendor.php**

```
<?php

namespace Amitshree\Marketplace\Helper;

class Vendor extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * Currently logged in customer
     *
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    protected $_currentCustomer;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
    * Retrive customer login status
    * @return bool
    */
    public function _isCustomerLogIn()
    {
        return $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }

    /** Retrive logged in customer
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    protected function _getCurrentCustomer()
    {
        return $this->getCustomer();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current customer
     *
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface|null
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if(!$this->_currentCustomer && $this->_isCustomerLogIn())
        {
            $this->_currentCustomer = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject();
        }
        return $this->_currentCustomer;
    }

    /**
     *  Check is vendor section allowed in sidebar
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isVendorInfoAllowedInSidebar()
    {
        if($this->isAVendorAndAccountApproved()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check if customer is a vendor and account is approved
     */
    public function isAVendorAndAccountApproved()
    {
        $this->_currentCustomer = $this->getCustomer();
        $isVendor = $this->_currentCustomer->getCustomAttribute('is_vendor')->getValue();
        $isApprovedAccount = $this->_currentCustomer->getCustomAttribute('approve_account')->getValue();

        if($isVendor && $isApprovedAccount)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Return vendor profile url
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVendorProfileUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('marketplace/vendor/profile');
    }
}
```

Comment: You should report bug to Module Author instead of asking question here.